# iOS App crashing after Google Analytics integration

Tags: ios, google-analytics, swift2, ios9.1

I am integrating Google Analytics in my Application [ iOS swift 2 ] 
with the help of: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift

I have done following steps: 
pod 'Google/Analytics' 
Placed Google provided code in App Delegate but when I run the application its crashing

[image: screen shot 2016-02-10 at 9 26 54 pm]

[image: screen shot 2016-02-10 at 9 25 46 pm]

[image: screen shot 2016-02-10 at 9 29 43 pm]

Update[Pod file screenshot]:
[image]

Update[GoogleService-Info.plist screenshot]:
[image]

Comment: can you show your pod file & configuration file.

Comment: @RohitKP: I have update the Question with Screenshot please check

Comment: also show the configuration file for google analytics

Comment: i.e, .GoogleService-Info.Plist

Comment: @RohitKP: please check attached SS of GoogleService-Info.plist

Comment: what is the crash log

Comment: BAD_ACCESS I have attached the the SS above

Comment: Did you add bridge-header file? Or you could use pod 'GoogleAnalytics' instead of pod 'Google/Analytics'. Also, You can get an idea from this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230442/viewcontroller-title-is-nil-after-init-of-google-analytics/35400485#35400485)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was crittercism bug: check [Press Release](http://docs.crittercism.com/release_notes/release_notes_ios.html)
I fixed that issue by updating crittercism library

Answer (score 1):

Please try below comments to create pod file on your mac and see

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Create a Podfile for the Google Analystics SDK for iOS and use it to install the API and its dependencies:

Create a file named Podfile in your project directory. This file defines your project’s dependencies, and is commonly referred to as a Podspec.

```
$ touch podfile
$ open -e podfile
```

Edit the Podfile and add your dependencies.

```
pod "Google/Analytics"
```

Save the Podfile.

Open a terminal and go to the directory containing the Podfile:

```
$ cd <project-path>
```

Run the pod install command. This will install the APIs specified in the Podspec, along with any dependencies they may have.

```
$ pod install
```